com.stripe.exception.RateLimitException overcome
I write some custom logic for update subscription in my project but at some point have began to receive error:
com.stripe.exception.RateLimitException: You are updating the subscription too frequently. Please slow down and try again or visit https://support.stripe.com/contact for help.; code: rate_limit; request-id: req_XXXXXXXXXXXX

    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleApiError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:215)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:143)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:67)
    at com.stripe.model.Subscription.update(Subscription.java:1240)
    at com.stripe.model.Subscription.update(Subscription.java:1186)
...

How to troubleshoot the situation? How can I know what kind and how many http requests Stripe Java SDK sends to server?

Stripe's standard rate limit errors happen when you exceed 100 reads or 100 writes per second[1]. Some objects like subscriptions have further restrictions on how often they can be updated, which looks to be what you are running in to here. This error happened because you updated this specific subscription more often than Stripe allows a specific subscription to be updated. If you run in to this error often in live mode, it will probably make sense to evaluate why you are making updates that frequently and see if you can combine or otherwise consolidate updates to make these API calls less frequently. Stripe's general advice on rate limits could still be helpful here: you can retry this call, but wait exponentially longer between each retry.
To answer your actual questions. Your Stripe dashboard[2] has logs of all of the API calls that you made. If you are unsure of what requests your application was making, you can look at the timeframe around when you got that error. The methods in Stripe's Java SDK map 1:1 with API calls that the library makes. So if you make a Subscription.update call, the SDK will make a single call to Stripe's server. You can configure the library to retry failed calls on errors like this[3], but the java SDK will still only make one request at a time for calls like this.
[1] https://docs.stripe.com/rate-limits
[2] https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs
[3] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java?tab=readme-ov-file#configuring-automatic-retries

Thank you for the answer! Do you know what subscription objects rate limiting is? I see in Stripe Dashboard logs currently I've done 1 subscription update request in ~10 mins and they aren't successful cause of that exception :(

Unfortunately I am not seeing documentation on that limit. If you reach out to Stripe's support, they may be able to tell you more about this. https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true
